# Is it possible to get Apples's approval if I declare the background task of my IM-like application as "voip" in info.plst file?

Tags: ios4, app-store, voip, appstore-approval

Is it possible to get Apples's approval if I declare the background task of my IM-like application as "voip" in info.plst file on iOS4? I hope that my app could keep a long connection to the server as long as possible.
Who's got this kind of experience?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per the rules & regulations if you are declaring it into info.plist file for the VOIP permission for the background tasks. You will have to make sure your application is providing such services.

If your application doesn't have such services & you just adding it to info.plist it will lead the rejection issue. Also make sure if you add into info.plist write the proper explanation for what you are using this service to clarify the user.

Hope this helps to everyone.